# providecommand for column vector

Tags: macros, vector

I'm trying to provide a command for a column vector. I defined this in the header:

```
\providecommand{\vector}[3]{\ensuremath{\left(
    \begin{matrix}
        #1 \\ 
        #2 \\ 
        #3
    \end{matrix}
    \right)}}
```

and then in the document:

```
\vector{-\sin\varphi}{\cos\varphi}{0}
```

but I get an error message:

```
Use of \vector doesn't match its definition.
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The LaTeX kernel already defines `\vector`, so your `\providecommand` does nothing. Choose a different name, say `\cvector`.

Answer (score 5):

With `\providecommand{\vector}[3]{...}` you are saying

> Dear LaTeX, if no command `\vector` is defined, please define it as I'd like to, otherwise do nothing and keep the previous definition

With `\newcommand{\vector}[3]{...}` you are saying

> Dear LaTeX, if no command `\vector` is defined, please define it as I'd like to, otherwise tell me by raising an error

With `\renewcommand{\vector}[3]{...}` you are saying

> Dear LaTeX, if a command `\vector` is defined, please redefine it as I'd like to, otherwise tell me by raising an error

For `\vector` we are in the situation where the command *is* already defined. So `\providecommand` has no effect and upon usage you either get an error or funny output. You might decide to go for the `\renewcommand` road, but this would be wrong: the kernel `\vector` command is used in picture mode and some package you load could use it: disaster would ensue.

Use a different name, like `\cvector`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `\parenVectorstack`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{stackengine} 
\stackMath
\begin{document} 
\[
\parenVectorstack{{-\sin\varphi} {\cos\varphi} {0}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]